# Clear Back stack in Android navigation Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to clear all fragments from the back stack when the home fragment is displayed.
In the navigation graph I added this action

```
<fragment
       android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
       android:name="com.test.navTest.ui.fragment.LoginFragment"
       android:label="fragment_login"
       tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment"
       >
       <action
           android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
           app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
           app:popUpTo="@+id/homeFragment"

           />
 </fragment>
```

and In the login fragment. I tried
 `findNavController().navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeFragment())`

and

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment)`

As I understand from the documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate
that `popUpTo` clears all the stack until the destination. But nothing is cleared when I press back.

UPDATE:
I changed this action to popUpTo=Login. It removed only the login fragment and not the 2 fragments before it. Should I add any parameter to the action of the fragments before the login

````
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />```
````

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me on clearing all fragments in the backstack is to add the graph id in the `popUpTo` value

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.test.navTest.ui.fragment.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    
    </fragment>
```

When I added `popUpTo = @+id/login_fragment`. It removed the login fragment only.